# React className with ternary operator add class 'null'

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to conditionally apply a class to my component using an expression like this:

```
.map(function(list, index) {
    <div className={"myClass " + (position === index ? 'active' : null)}>
}
```

But it keeps adding `null` as class, with an end result like this:

```
<div class="myClass active">...
<div class="myClass null">...
```

This is a simple example, with only 2 class names, so I could just replace `null` with the default class name. But in a more complex layout, I would need to duplicate the same name over and over again.

Is there a better approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could use an empty string `''` instead of null like:

```
.map(function(list, index) {
    <div className={"myClass " + (position === index ? 'active' : '')}>
}
```

Also map should return a value:

```
 .map(function(list, index) {
     return <div className={"myClass " + (position === index ? 'active' : '')}>;
 }
```

Comment: This still means to create lots of empty strings. Isn't it a performance overhead compared to leaving the attribute `undefined` (memory + garbage collection + setting overhead)?

Comment: With regards to performance, that's probably a micro-optimization concern. Rather, the generated HTML is bloated and difficult to parse in the event that we use dev tools to review or troubelshoot.

Answer (score 4):

If you have multiple classes, you might consider building the list of classes from an array:

```
var classes = ["myClass"];

if (position === index) {
   classes.push('active');
}

return (
   <div className={classes.join(' ')}>
      ...
   </div>
);
```

You can also consider using a helper function that will generate the `className` string from an object like this:

```
var classes = {
    myClass: true,
    active: position === index     
};
```

[classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) is one such utility (not the only one).

Answer (score 2):

Remove the space from `"myClass "` to `"myClass"`, then replace `null` with an empty string `""`

```
.map(function(list, index) {
    <div className={"myClass" + (position === index ? 'active' : "")}>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

just use https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames:

usage example:

```
<div className={cn({"active": position === index })} ></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

React Solution:

```
className={`myClass ${index ? "active" : ""}`}
```

Different syntax

```
className={`myClass ${index && "active"}`}
```

Comment: Note the second one can result in things like `className="myClass false"` (or null, undefined, etc) which may not be what you want. The first one is what I use most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Use `&&` short-circuiting: `className={"myClass " + (position === index && 'active')}`

In this way, if `position === index` is false, because we are using `&&`, we short-circuit. JS skips over `'active'` and we just move on with our lives.

Comment: This will print "false" as a className if position !== index. Just be aware of this.

Comment: Ugh! Good point - not much better than seeing `null`. :(